# PostgreSQL: is there a better way to query a table with many columns but only need to be grouped by one of these columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with many columns (I know it's not good), but now I want to query the table but only need to group the results by only one of the column, so a general way is:

```
select table_name.id,
       table_name.account_no,
       ....(all the other column name)
from   table_name
where  some conditions
group by table_name.bank_name
```

so I need to write all the other columns for this single query. I'm wondering if there's a better way to do that?

Comment: To output the other columns you need to use aggregate functions.  See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html

Comment: You can’t select all columns and group by only one.

Comment: Why are you using GROUP BY if you're not aggregating? Are you perhaps looking for [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) instead?